# Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать подобную кнопку в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: кнопка]

Помогите пожалуйста, необходимо сделать нечто подобное на xaml, заранее благодарю

Comment: а что вы уже сделали, с чего начали, какой код написали? Здесь за вас задачу решать никто не будет! Начните, хотя бы с того что, математически опишите нарисованную фигуру.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать векторную графику.

Допустим открываем изображение в .png формате через Inkscape, далее жмем Path-Trace Bitmap (Shift+Alt+B), играемся с настройками:

[image: Inkscape]

После нажатия OK у нас будет создан дополнительно слой с векторной графикой, проверяем что бы все было гладко и как нужно, удаляем слой с .png сзади и сохраняем наш вектор (Files - Save As...).

Имея файл мы можем из него вытянуть нужную нам информацию, открываем файл через любой текстовый редактор, это обычный xml формат. Спускаемся  самый низ и видим раздел `path`, у меня он такой:

```
<path
     style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:1.33333337"
     d="m 241.41823,107.11833 c -15.54109,-4.28541 -24.3626,-10.942132 -39.85927,-30.077862 -16.5635,-20.4531 -5.8525,-18.6543 -111.077607,-18.6543 -77.06159,0 -88.9123671,-0.25947 -88.9123671,-1.94667 0,-1.68335 12.0381421,-1.99896 88.9999971,-2.33333 103.654437,-0.45034 93.982727,1.02222 108.306537,-16.49016 13.28726,-16.24508 22.42419,-24.55061 32.02679,-29.11254 8.66667,-4.1173004 8.66667,-4.1173004 415.99999,-4.1173004 407.3334,0 407.3334,0 416,4.1173004 9.6026,4.56193 18.7396,12.86746 32.0268,29.11254 14.3296,17.5194 4.5525,16.03992 108.9732,16.48981 77.554,0.33413 89.6667,0.64933 89.6667,2.33333 0,1.68781 -11.9256,1.94702 -89.579,1.94702 -105.9948,0 -95.1748,-1.80627 -111.7443,18.6543 -15.7393,19.43531 -24.3648,25.862592 -40.4586,30.147612 -9.8256,2.6161 -800.87552,2.54802 -810.36887,-0.0697 z"
     id="path3690"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

Внутри него есть самая длинная строка `d`, которая содержит все точки нашей фигуры, смело копируем ее. Все, остается сделать стиль...

В xaml за векторную графику отвечает компонент `Path`, значит на его основе можем сделать простенький стиль для кнопок:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Data="m 241.41823,107.11833 c -15.54109,-4.28541 -24.3626,-10.942132 -39.85927,-30.077862 -16.5635,-20.4531 -5.8525,-18.6543 -111.077607,-18.6543 -77.06159,0 -88.9123671,-0.25947 -88.9123671,-1.94667 0,-1.68335 12.0381421,-1.99896 88.9999971,-2.33333 103.654437,-0.45034 93.982727,1.02222 108.306537,-16.49016 13.28726,-16.24508 22.42419,-24.55061 32.02679,-29.11254 8.66667,-4.1173004 8.66667,-4.1173004 415.99999,-4.1173004 407.3334,0 407.3334,0 416,4.1173004 9.6026,4.56193 18.7396,12.86746 32.0268,29.11254 14.3296,17.5194 4.5525,16.03992 108.9732,16.48981 77.554,0.33413 89.6667,0.64933 89.6667,2.33333 0,1.68781 -11.9256,1.94702 -89.579,1.94702 -105.9948,0 -95.1748,-1.80627 -111.7443,18.6543 -15.7393,19.43531 -24.3648,25.862592 -40.4586,30.147612 -9.8256,2.6161 -800.87552,2.54802 -810.36887,-0.0697 z" >
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1A3E53" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1A3E53" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.25"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.75"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                            <Path.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                            </Path.Effect>
                        </Path>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="8" Text="Привет мир!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Поясняю:

- `Viewbox` - первый элемент, который изменяет размер внутреннего объекта автоматически, без него наш вектор был бы очень большого размера, нам ведь нужна небольшая кнопка...
- `Grid` - следующий элемент, это сетка, которая позволяет располагать внутренние объекты друг на друге, что нам и нужно...
- `Path` - наш вектор, скопированный код из файла мы задаем в свойство `Data`, ну а также наводим марафет (покраска и все дела).
- `TextBlock` - это собственно наш текст, что бы он менял размер автоматически, мы можем его засунуть в `Viewbox`. Я не стал тут брать текст из `Content`, это уж сами...

Все, создаем простую кнопку и смотрим как все будет смотреться:

[image: Result]

Вот и все! Вам останется поколдовать над стилем, добавить триггеры, цвета получше сделать и так далее. В общем удачи!

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Kchipson Да на здоровье. Удачи в изучение WPF! ;-)