# Стиль Xaml для кнопки "крестик"

Tags: c#, wpf

В триггерах, сеттерах и т д не очень силён, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать стиль, чтобы при наведении на кнопку, она постепенно , слегка поменяла цвет, например с белого на чутка сероватый, и т.д
P.s моя кнопка, это изображение "крестик" - то есть tile brush , и мне нужно чтобы стиль работал так, чтобы не сама область кнопки по стилю работала, а именно изображение этого крестика в кнопке, как то это можно сделать? Или есть проще способ?

Comment: 1. Не советую использовать картинки для таких простых элементов, используйте вектор. 2. Вам достаточно анимировать прозрачность.

Comment: А можно примерный код в хамле, как добиться анимации прозрачности? И под вектором вы имеете ввиду векторное изображение туда вставить или как?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Создадим новый стиль, в `TargetType` задаем `{x:Type Button}`. Внутри стиля зададим задний фон и фон текста:

  ```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="CadetBlue"/>
  </Style>
  ```
- Далее переопределим шаблон кнопки, пусть это будет векторное изображение, которое будет автоматически подстраиваться под объект. Все цвета и размеры мы возьмем от шаблона:

  ```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="CadetBlue"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                      <Viewbox>
                          <Canvas Width="24" Height="24" x:Name="Canvas">
                              <Path Data="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                          </Canvas>
                      </Viewbox>
                  </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```
- Теперь остается сделать анимацию при наведении/потери фокуса мыши. Так, как вы хотите сделать "слегка сероватый" цвет, то тут отлично подойдет анимация прозрачности. Нам нужно создать два `EventTrigger` внутри `ControlTemplate`, которые проиграют нужную нам анимацию:

  ```
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation 
                      Storyboard.TargetName="Canvas"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5" Duration="0:0:.8" />
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation 
                      Storyboard.TargetName="Canvas"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:.8" />
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  ```

Можно заметить, что с помощью `Storyboard.TargetName` мы меняем только прозрачность самого "креста" (векторной графики). Если вам нужно менять прозрачность всей кнопки, то уберите это, либо задайте имя на другой элемент стиля.

Результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: А если мне понадобится любое другое векторное изображение, например "свернуть" , то с ним алгоритм тот же самый? И обязательно ли векторное изображение использовать? Если же я допустим png изображение готовое скачал, я могу с ним такой алгоритм реализовать?
И тот код, который вы дали выше, мне его поместить в отдельный xaml файл с этим стилем, а затем применить к кнопке?

Comment: Суть вектора в универсальности. Например вариант выше при любом размере будет выглядеть одинаково хорошо, а вот изображение (png/jpg и др.) имеют фиксированный размер, к примеру 20х20, если вы начнете его увеличивать, то он будет весь в пикселях и совершенно не читаем. Также размер, картинка обычно весит ~100-1000кб, а вектор - это как видите всего лишь строка кода. Если вы хотите хороший дизайн, который будет хорошо смотреться и с которым вам будет приятно работать при его создание, то вектор обязателен. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553) я писал как создать вектор из PNG.

Comment: А код выше, куда нужно вписывать? Как я выше написал? Просто в xaml не очень силён пока, учусь

Comment: По поводу стиля - да, вы можете использовать изображение, всего лишь перепишите вид кнопки. Для "свернуть" тоже самое, только каждому стилю дайте имя (для того, что бы он не применялся ко всем Button элементам (прим: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="CloseStyle">` и далее у кнопки `<Button Style="Стиль"`).

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам огромное, без вас, я бы наверно вечно мучался, ибо с функционалом всё более менее, а вот дизайн хочется в современном стиле, а не со стандартным windows окном:)

Comment: @Jaffyel Для современного дизайна старайтесь использовать как можно меньше изображений, всякие крестики, бордюры, панели и прочее - все кодом. Также в интернете есть уйма готовых вариантов иконок и другой различной векторной графики. Например [вот](https://materialdesignicons.com/). В общем удачи в написание хорошего стиля!

Comment: Можно вам еще вопросик задать?

Comment: @Jaffyel Мне - можно. Но только если это связано с текущим вопросом. Иначе стоит оформить его как новый вопрос на SO. Таковы правила)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943203/Лаунчер-для-игры-доработка
Вот

Comment: А я когда сделал действие закрытия формы по нажатию на крестик, то он закрывает её, только если я таргет прямо на него наведу, а как сделать, чтобы он впринципе выделял всю кнопку, и куда бы я не нажал срабатывала анимация на крест и можно было нажать?

Comment: Задайте задний фон прозрачным (`Transparent`).