# Не могу передать Action в UserControl [ C# ] [ WPF ]

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, usercontrol

В UserControl есть Border, на него накинуто событие Mouse Down. Также есть свойство типа Action.

При вызове Mouse Down надо выполнить полученный Action.

Что бы не делал, он (Action) попросту не передаётся в User Control. Подскажите причину, если знаете. Или, пожалуйста, скажите как правильно такое реализовать (передачу и реализацию метода / комманды) в User Control.

> PS: Не сделал Button вместо Border, потому что никак не мог убрать
> подсветку кнопки при наведении.

**Свойство в UC:**

```
public Action ButtonMouseDown
        {
            get { return (Action)GetValue(ButtonMouseDownProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonMouseDownProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonMouseDown.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonMouseDownProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonMouseDown", typeof(Action), typeof(ButtonIndicatorsInfo));
```

**Mouse Down в UC:**

```
private void buttonMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ButtonMouseDown != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(ButtonMouseDown);
            }
        }
```

**Как я назначаю Action:**

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            ActionForUC = new Action(ClickMethod);
        }
        public Action ActionForUC { get; set; }
        private void ClickMethod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Тест");
        }
```

В свойствах у UC указываю:

```
ButtonMouseDown="{Binding ActionForUC}"
```

Comment: Не то вы делаете, ох не то. 1. Если это кнопка, то и надо использовать кнопку (`Button`), которая будет иметь свой вид (например вот [крестик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943118/220553), без всяких выделений и прочего). 2. Если вы работаете с привязками, то всякие клики обрабатываются при помощи команд (`ICommand`), которые вы и должны передавать и привязывать как `Command = "{Binding SomeCommand}"`. 3. Если вам нужны именно события, то они также [привязываются к ICommand](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/917223/220553).

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что не то я делаю :(
Хочется сделать свой классный и полезный контрол, какие-то косяки исправляю, но на какие-то даже в интернете решение найти не могу.
Я могу обратиться за личной помощью к Вам в дискорде?

Comment: Что мешает сделать это здесь? Вы наверно для этого сюда и пришли, верно?

Comment: Не хотелось бы засорять сайт и тему

Comment: Здесь правильно работают с ICommand?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3a6d09d-cdde-4571-9352-0b2e40088796/create-a-command-in-a-usercontrol?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте команды

##### UserControl

Разметка

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
                        <Button Content="Click me!" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

DependencyProperty

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ICommand Command
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
}

public object CommandParameter
{
    get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
}
```

Вызов

```
if (Command?.CanExecute?.Invoke(CommandParameter) ?? true)
{
    Command?.Execute?.Invoke(CommandParameter);
}
```

##### Использование

Разметка

```xml
<local:MyUserControl Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="Hello World"/>
```

Дополнительный класс

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Код вьюмодели

```
private ICommand _myCommand;

public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}, parameter => true);
```

Это совершенно стандартная команда, обычная `Button` имеет точно такую же с точно таким же параметром.

Дополнительно, если у вашего контрола есть свойство `Enabled`, которое визуально "отключает" контрол, то в случае если `CanExecute` возвращает `false`, то надо применить стиль отключенного контрола к юзерконтролу. Чтобы отслеживать изменение `CanExecute`, нужно подписаться на событие `CanExecuteChanged` команды при изменении самой команды в DP. `Button` делает точно так же.

Если у вас в разметке юзерконтрола есть `Button` или другой кликабельный контрол с поддержкой команды, то можете просто пробросить команду и параметр туда через [`TemplateBinding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension), тогда реализовать логику вызова команды не придется.

Comment: Не срабатывает команда, не понимаю почему.
Сделал всё по Вашим примерам.

[Видеоролик](https://youtu.be/n_yMhb3ogkA)


[Продолжение](https://youtu.be/H_UoBKxc5Ws)

Comment: @DmitryYalchik потому что сразу надо было выкладывать XAML юзерконтрола, а не прятаться по ютубам. Юзерконтролу не нужна вьюмодель, потому что он часть View, и DataContext ему надо назначать не внутри его кода, а снаружи. Поэтому лучше всего для разметки использовать ControlTemplate а не Content. Пример разметки я добавил в ответ. А не работало, потому что у вас биндинг к свойству, а не к свойству зависимости был, то есть вы использовали контрол как вьюмодель для самого себя. А что надо во вьюмодели обычно сделать, чтобы привязки пахали? Правильно - INotifyPropertyChanged. :) Никакой магии.

Comment: @DmitryYalchik не забудьте убрать `DataContext = this`, а то опять работать не будет.

Comment: Вот блин, я новичок в данной теме. Учусь)) Спасибо большое, попробую

Comment: @DmitryYalchik заработало?

Comment: Сделал через ControlTemplate, добавил INotifyPropertyChanged.
Всё равно не фурычит


[Видео](https://youtu.be/GzKs9wFPtdU)

Comment: @DmitryYalchik это даже не смешно, вы забыли TemplateBinding для CommandParameter, if в команде проверяет, есть ли параметр и вызывает MessageBox если есть, а у вас он не доехал. Точки останова ставить надо научиться. Без умений отлаживать, вам будет тяжело написать что-то вменяемое.

Comment: Я указал, оно не работает. Расставит точки, сборка дебаг - не отлавливает, соответственно не вызывается, как я понимаю. Убрал проверку на параметр, тоже не останавливается.

Всё больше и больше желание бросить эту идею и не напрягать других людей =(

Comment: @DmitryYalchik Закройте проект, удалите папки bin и obj, запакуйте в архив, залейте на обменник, дайте ссылку, я гляну. Все ваши проблемы от того что вы делаете под диктовку не разбираясь в том, а как же оно на самом деле работает. Следовательно и лечить как не понятно. Надо начать разбираться.

Comment: Да, я понимаю это. Но имея хотя бы что-то - можно искать инфу по элементам.
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/zqewNpYBgGAQtQ

Comment: Прошу прощёния, дочернюю папку скинул.
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/I8pEpachv5b8yQ

Comment: @DmitryYalchik я ща поправлю, но начните с того чтобы подробно сравнить, как я задал теплейт в юзерконтроле, и как вы. Выглядит как просто невнимательность и самодеятельность.

Comment: У меня обновление страницы стоит с привязкой к комментарию, не видел обновление ответа. Сейчас попробую ещё разок))

Comment: @DmitryYalchik https://disk.yandex.ru/d/IOyvLQvKPDrkjg все правки в разметке юзерконтрола, внимательно посмотрите в 3 места, в свой старый вариант, в то что я прислал и в разметку юзерконтрола из ответа выше.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Я брал таргет тайп кнопки, а надо было самого контрола. Тогда и свойство с текстом будет работать (обычный биндинг поменял на темплейт биндинг).

Теперь знаю, что надо через `<UserControl.Resources>`, но не понимаю почему так

Comment: @DmitryYalchik вы делаете шаблон для юзерконтрола, используя тип юзерконтрола, логично вроде. Напрямую UserControl.Template не задать, потому что вам нужен именно MyUserControl, а не его родитель, но это уже недостатки XAML. А из стиля темплейт подхватывается без проблем, поэтому через ресурсы. WPF не везде гладкий и удобный.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам огромное! Доброй ночи)