# Не работает LeftClick в MouseAction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

у меня возникла проблема: в MainWindow.xaml я добавляю UserControl, и к нему я хочу привязать InputBindings, но в MouseAction работает только RightClick:

```
<uc:MenuButton Title="О программе" 
                               IsActive="{Binding AboutProgram_Button.IsActive}"
                               x:Name="AboutProgram_Button" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold">
                    <uc:MenuButton.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickAboutProgram_ButtonCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding AboutProgram_Button.Name}"
                                      MouseAction="RightClick"/>
                    </uc:MenuButton.InputBindings>
                </uc:MenuButton>
```

Вот сам UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartAssistant.Views.UserControls.MenuButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartAssistant.Views.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="menuButton"
         d:DesignWidth="200">

<Grid Margin="0 -17">
    <Button x:Name="btn" Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=menuButton}"
                       Style="{DynamicResource menuButtonText}" 
                       Width="175"
                       IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Width="20"
          Height="85"
          Panel.ZIndex="0"
          Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=btn}">

        <Path Fill="{DynamicResource BackgroundLightBrush}" Stretch="Fill"
              Data="M0 20.7C15 20 26.5 12 27 0V87.6C26 75 15.1 67.5 0 67V24Z"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Стиль menuButton:

```
<Style x:Key="menuButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25 0 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="45" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <!--<EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20 0 0 20">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6b768b" />
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=menuButton, Path=IsActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6b768b" />
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Как мне можно использовать LeftClick в MouseAction или другие параметры для MouseAction?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Видимо потому что что-то перехватывает левый клик, что-то лежащее поверх того, где биндинг прописан. Попробуйте задать дочерним элементам IsHitTestVisible=False. По текущей вырезке кода понятно явно, в чем проблема, невозможно. А потом, зачем вам через интпутбиндинг привязывать команду на левый клик, если ее можно привязать на сам элемент Command=..., она и будет по левому клику срабатывать.

Comment: Ну, вы добавили кода. Ничего не поменялось, что мешает Command для кнопеи задать? Пробросьте команду через DP в реальную кнопку. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1441493/373567