# Ошибка StackOverflow при вызове InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Делал контроллер стрелок для инк-декрементации численного значения в TextBox'е:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=qqq, Path=Text}" />
<ctrls:UpDownCtrl x:Name="qqq" />
```

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка StackOverflow:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ломается конструктор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UpDownCtrl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="prod_bw.Ctrls.UpDownCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:prod_bw.Ctrls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="22">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UpDownCtrl />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">
        <TextBox x:Name="value" Text="{Binding Text}" Width="32" PreviewTextInput="value_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="value_Pasting" MaxLength="3" />
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="11" Width="13">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="11" Text="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" />
            </Button>
            <Button Height="11" Width="13">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="11" Text="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UpDownCtrl.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace prod_bw.Ctrls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UpDownCtrl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UpDownCtrl : UserControl
    {
        private static readonly Regex onlyNumberRegex = new Regex("[^0-9]");

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public UpDownCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void value_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = onlyNumberRegex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

        private void value_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
            {
                string text = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));
                if (onlyNumberRegex.IsMatch(text))
                {
                    e.CancelCommand();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запускайте под отладкой, и шаг за шагом (F10 вроде по умолчанию) идите по своему коду, так найдете зацикленность, ее и устраняйте. По коду из вопроса предположу, что вы задаете `DataContext` на тот-же самый контрол, что и отображаете, вам WPF и создает сначала контрол, потом новый DataContext, потом опять контрол, потом опять DataContext, и так по кругу.

Comment: Что в стеке вызовов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рендер XAML создает экземпляр класса `UpDownCtrl`

```xml
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:UpDownCtrl />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

То есть вызывает его конструктор

А конструктор в свою очередь вызывает рендер XAML

```
public UpDownCtrl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

И так далее по кругу до тех пор, пока не выскочит `StackOverflowException`

---

Чтобы решить, вот это

```xml
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:UpDownCtrl />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Надо убрать

Конструктор изменить так

```
public UpDownCtrl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

А чтобы подсказки были в XAML по контексту, нужно добавить вот это в атрибуты контрола

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:UpDownCtrl,IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

Но вообще `DataContext` контролу обычно не задают и никак не используют. Для привязок в контроле вместо INPC свойств используйют `DependencyProperty`. К которым можно привязаться через `TemplateBinding` из `ControlTemplate` - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1441493/373567).

Тогда вы сможете при создании юзерконтрола в визуальном дереве родительского окна задавать ему нужные атрибуты и управлять его логикой. А приватными данными юзерконтрола можно оперировать через обычные обработчики событий и внутреннюю логику.

Внутри юзерконтрола не обязательно устраивать MVVM, очень часто достаточно только View. А все привязки DP к данным производятся снаружи обычным способом, как вы это делаете с любым другим стандартным контролом.