# DependencyProperty как привязать его к сеттеру

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 public class Cust: ComboBox
{
 #region CornerRadius у combobox и выпадающего списка
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadius_CustomComboBox_Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    nameof(CornerRadius_CustomComboBox), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(6.0)));
    
            public static void SetCornerRadius_Cust(UIElement element, CornerRadius value) => element.SetValue(CornerRadius_CustomComboBox_Property, value);
    
            public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius_Cust(UIElement element) => (CornerRadius)element.GetValue(CornerRadius_CustomComboBox_Property);
            public CornerRadius CornerRadius_CustomComboBox
            {
                get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadius_CustomComboBox_Property); }
                set { SetValue(CornerRadius_CustomComboBox_Property, value); }
            }
            #endregion
}
```

wpf

```
Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="Test" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:Cust}">
            <Setter Property="Background_Cust" Value="Violet"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush_Cust" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius_Cust" Value="10 1 1 1"></Setter>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:Cust Style="{StaticResource Test}" Margin="0,0,0,325">
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
             <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
        </local:Cust>
    </Grid>
```

Я хочу использовать CornerRadius_CustomComboBox в сеттере, но в ошибках пишется `Свойство "CornerRadius_Cust" не является свойством DependencyProperty. Для использования в разметке не присоединенные свойства необходимо предоставить целевому типу с доступным свойством экземпляра "CornerRadius_Cust". Для присоединенных свойств в объявляющем типе должны быть представлены статические методы "GetCornerRadius_Cust" и "SetCornerRadius_Cust".` Хотя при запуске углы закругляются у элемента.

Comment: Все верно, у вас единственное DP `CornerRadius_CustomComboBox`, других нет. Не нужно определять `Get*` и `Set*`, своства достаточно. Пример работы с DP https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1441493/373567

Comment: @aepot Я могу использовать свойство так: ```<local:Cust Style="{StaticResource Test}" CornerRadius_Cust="30" Margin="0,0,0,325">
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
        </local:Cust>``` Но если я  указываю в сеттере стиля как в вопросе, мне выдает ошибку из вопроса, в окне пишется недопустимая разметка, снизу ошибка. Хотя я могу запустить проект и все работает... Я удалил  ```Get* и Set*``` и оставил только свойство, это мне не помогло

Comment: @aepot я написал в примере не вест код, у меня этих DP  штук 10, странно что какие то доступны, какие то нет

Comment: @aepot ```Пример работы с DP ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1441493/373567``` У меня другая проблема, если надо, то могу выложить проект, суть в том что я наследуюсь от ComboBox добавляю новые свойства(DP) затем создаю вызываю в xaml контрол и применяю ему стиль из словаря, стиль использует из dp цвета, настройки и прочее

Comment: Чтобы заработало `CornerRadius_Cust`, вам следует объявить `DependencyProperty CornerRadius_CustProperty`, либо так `<Setter Property="CornerRadius_CustomComboBox" Value="10 1 1 1"></Setter>` а `SetCornerRadius_Cust` и `GetCornerRadius_Cust` удалить, они не нужны. Логика ясна?

Comment: @aepot как оказалось с `Set***` `Get***` это без разницы в моем случае. Оказалась ошибка совсем в другом была, сейчас опубликую ответ

Comment: я вам об этом и писал выше.

Comment: @aepot точно, я сначала сделал потом прочитал, можете опубликовать это ответом, а я свой удалю

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть свойство `DP`с именем `CornerRadius_Cust` Сейчас моей самой большой ошибкой было то что в именование `DependencyProperty` я нарушил правило именования. Нужно к имени строго прописывать `Property` без лишних букв или символов.
Для сравнения:
Оригинальное имя `CornerRadius_Cust`
Имя для DependencyProperty: `CornerRadius_CustProperty`
Если указываете `Get` или `Set` то после этого префикса, также должно идти имя которое вашего свойства.
Сам код для примера.

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadius_CustProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
nameof(CornerRadius_Cust), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(Cust), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(6.0)));

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius_Cust
        {
            get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadius_CustProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadius_CustProperty, value); }
        }
```