# Подскажите, как можно реализовать частичные круги средствами WPF

Tags: wpf

Опыт WPF не большой. Могу предположить, что можно сделать такие круги типом "Ellipse" или используя Geometry.
Подскажите в каком направлении лучше идти, или еще какие-нибудь варианты реализации таких частичных кругов

Думаю, ответ пригодиться не только мне, т.к. стал замечать, что подобных дизайнов стало появляться больше.
[image: Профиль]

ссылка на изображение с dribbble https://dribbble.com/shots/3135884-Settings-Sidemenu-unused-element-part-11?utm_source=Clipboard_Shot&utm_campaign=prakhar&utm_content=Settings%20%2B%20Sidemenu%20(unused%20element%20part%2011)&utm_medium=Social_Share

Comment: Скорее всего это кривые Безье, они есть в примитивах и можно сложить Path из них. Но по хорошему можно сделать простую картинку на фон.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, картинка вряд ли подойдет, т.к. при возможном масштабировании может размыть. К тому же хотелось выяснить, как это средствами WPF реализовать. В данный момент тоже дошел до Path, в Blend с ними легче совладать, но пока не очень понятно, если, например захотят, например, увеличить ширину или высоту этого окна в 3 раза, кривые масштабируются без проблем?

Comment: Мне кажется тут надо поступить [данным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553) способом. Нарисовали в фотошопе нужную графику, преобразовали в вектор и применили в WPF.  По поводу масштаба - посмотрите в примере на элемент `ViewBox`, он автоматически подгоняет размер, а так, как там вектор - "пикселяции" не будет.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответы, сделал по вашим советам, использовал Microsoft Blend - инструмент "Перо" - получил Path на выходе

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю наиболее правильно использовать [ArcSegment](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.arcsegment?view=netframework-4.8). данный класс можно использовать в составе [PathGeometry](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pathgeometry?view=netframework-4.8), который в свою очередь помещается в объект [Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.path?view=netframework-4.8). [Пример с анимацией](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-size-of-an-arcsegment).