# C# WPF Плохо рендерит иконку при масштабировании дисплея в Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, scaling

Вот изображение при 125%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и нормальное при 100%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<Image Source="/Icon/SearchIcon304x400.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Width="304" Height="400"/>
```

Использовать вектор?

Comment: [Откуда «мыло» в WPF и как с ним бороться](https://habr.com/ru/post/216833/)

Comment: Старайтесь максимально убрать изображения из проекта, они во первых много весят, а во вторых плохо масштабируются (как вы уже заметили). Для решения данной проблемы придумали вектор, это некий набор точек, который программа успешно может масштабировать без потерь качества. Конкретно вашу иконку вы можете преобразовать сами в вектор (об этом я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553)), либо можете взять готовое (например [здесь](https://materialdesignicons.com/)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да я понял уже, раньше был вектор но я подумал png немного рендер ускорит, inkscape отлично svg в xaml делает (ну почти)

Comment: У меня единственная растровая картинка в приложении - его иконка.