# Как рисовать волны на фоне средствами wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать подобные элементы дизайна, как на картинке, а именно волны на фоне в левой части формы. Как это можно реализовать средствами wpf ?
Хочется именно разметкой, а не картинкой[image: Пример]

Comment: Нарисуйте в фотошопе, [преобразуйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553) в вектор и накладывайте друг на друга с прозрачностью.

Comment: Создаете векторное изображение в любом векторном редакторе, сохраняете в SVG файл, затем конвертируете его в XAML (есть утилиты), и готово. Вручную прописывать векторы - это совсем не круто. Но если очень хочется, то [можно](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/17.3.php).