# Как выровнять элементы внутри DrawingGroup?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Я попытался через DrawingGroup нарисовать кнопку "Power", но столкнулся с проблемой выравнивания элементов.

В гугле не нашёл как можно выровнять эти 2 элемента относительно друг друга (возможно не умею гуглить).

Также не исключаю момент, что я не правильно работаю с DrawingGroup и Geometry элементами.

[image: Рисование кнопки]

[image: Использование нарисованного изображения]

[image: Результат]

Comment: Мне кажется, вы мудрите, не? Уже есть куча готовых иконок в виде вектора, берете любую понравившуюся и используете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , извиняюсь, не знал что можно векторное изображение конвертировать в XAML код, только вот как это сделать? (Что-то я ничего не нагуглил особо)

Comment: [Готовый набор](https://materialdesignicons.com/) (прям копируйте и вставляйте), [свое изображение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553), еще есть шрифты (на подобии `FontAwesome`).